# How to search in a column that has been converted to index in dataframe?

Tags: pandas

This is my dataframe

```
d = {'id':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d'],
 'seg':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
 'type':['y','y','y','z','z','z','y','y','z','z','z','y']
}
df= pd.DataFrame(d)

df1 = df.set_index(['id','type'])
```

Why am I not able to use  `df1.loc[df1['id'] == 'a']` to filter for `a`in `id` column?

What is the way to do it for columns which are set as index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try `query` notice this will carry the index id as well :-)

```
df1.query("id=='a'")
         seg
id type     
a  y       1
   y       2
   y       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `id` is part of `df1`'s index now, not a column. You can use `[]` access on column only. But since `id` is first level index, you can do:

```
df1.loc['a']
```

which gives:

```
      seg
type     
y       1
y       2
y       3
```